# How to dismiss view controller opened with present?

Tags: ios, swift

Pretty new to Swift so forgive my ignorance. I have a navigation controller which is linked to a View controller called Profile. In `ProfileViewController.swift` I have it to where it opens up another view controller if no profile exists. Here's an example of what I have at the moment:
[image]

```
// ProfileViewController.swift

var profileExists = 0
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Check if user has a profile. If so, go to view page; otherwise, bring up new profile view.
    if profileExists != 1 {
        // Create new profile page.
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EditProfileController") as? EditProfileViewController {

            present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        print("Need to create new profile.")
    }

    //Scroll view size
    ScrollView.contentSize.height = 1000
}

// Cancel button was pressed.
@IBAction func unwindToHomeScreen(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {

}
```

What I'm trying to do is link my "Cancel" bar button in the "EditProfile" view controller to dismiss it if the user clicks cancel. However, trying to replicate an example from a tutorial isn't working. I can't control + drag the Cancel button to the Exit button and use a defined unwind segue. Not quite sure why just yet.

Any ideas on the best way I should be trying to dismiss this view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple call

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks. So I understand this code will dismiss, but how do I link the Cancel button to the actual function? I have it defined as `@IBAction func dismissProfileView(sender: AnyObject) {` inside of the EditProfileViewController.swift, but I don't see it when I right click the view controller from the left side in order to drag it to the cancel button.

Comment: @LewlSauce So in the linking view of storyboard, you cannot are seeing some wrong swift file on your right panel?

Comment: Ah ok I misunderstood. I was able to get it going. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @LewlSauce NP Please mark as correct answer and let me know if you need further helps :)